# Meteogram with Vertical Profile in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

A couple of months ago, I made a meteogram with NCL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPBR1.jpg)

It works great, but I would like to improve it, making it again in highcharts. I know there is already a meteogram in highcharts, but honestly it's too basic. So I decided to make one like mine.

I know the last 4 graphics perhaps could be made using this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

But I have no idea of how to make the vertical profile. Maybe It could be made modifying a "large heatmap" somehow (look for highcharts large heatmap, I can't post more than two links)

Yet, I don't know if could be possible to overlay wind arrows all along, to show the wind direction. Anybody have an idea or suggestion about all this? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!!

Comment: I think you would be making life difficult for yourself if you try to do it in Highcharts, Personally I would use an HTML5 Canvas and a library such as fabric.js to create the meteogram.

Comment: What about using the `polygon` series type? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polygon

Comment: I think that your starting point should be familiarised with [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) - it will allow you to render own shapes. You can see also [meteogram example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-meteogram/) which can you the idea how the shapes drawn on an existing chart.